# Delete statement in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-delete

I have these tables:

- `Account` (`account-number (PK), branch-name (FK), balance`)
- `Branch` (`branch-name (PK), branch-city, assets`)

Could someone explain me what is the difference between the following two statements? I executed both of them at my database and the result of deleted rows was the same. Am I missing something?

```
delete from account
where [branch-name] = 'London'
```

and

```
delete from account
where [branch-name] in (select [branch-name]
                        from branch
                        where [branch-name]='London')
```

Comment: Query #2 is just a way more complicated (and much less intuitive) version of #1 - they both do the same thing in the end.....

Comment: What is the purpose of this?

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Do you suggest using one of these two? Does the  2nd way look more professional if we can say so?

Comment: If the difference pointed out by Guffa is really _intended_, then the 2nd one is _correct_ and the 1st one not. If referential integrity is enforced, however, the 2nd one is just redundant and slower.

Comment: There are two things that doesn't seem completely professional with a query like the second. 1) It doesn't make much sense to check if the branch exists when *deleting* a record, it should have been created in the first place if the branch for it doesn't exist. 2) For a normalised database the `account` table shouldn't have a copy of the branch name, but rather have a branch id that connects it to the branch, and the branch name should exist only in the `branch` table.

Answer (score 5):

The difference is that the second query checks if the branch name exists in the `branch` table before deleting it in the `account` table.

If the branch name exists in the `account` table, but not in the `branch` table, then it won't be deleted from the `account` table.

The first query deletes the record from the `account` table regardles whether the branch exists in the `branch` table.

Comment: Click . . . Those are different table names in the subquery and the outer query.

Answer (score 0):

Those queries do exactly the same.
In first you simply delede from `account` where `branch-name` column value is `'London'`

In second you do the same, but you check if `branch-name` is in **list**(result of query) returned by 
`select [branch-name] from branch where [branch-name]='London'`, 
but it always returns list of elements `'London'` (because of `where` clause).

So the result for both queries is the same.